# Outliers how to deal with them and do replacing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels, outliers

Im trying to find out all my outliers in my dataframe using python. And replace them by the mean value of this column of my dataframe. I tried these line of code but.

```
for c in df:
    def replace(c):
        mean, std = c.mean(), c.std()
        outliers = (c- mean).abs() > 3*std
        c[outliers] = mean
        return c
    df= df.transform(replace)
```

when i tried to test the existence of outliers in all columns of my dataframe using this line of code `z= np.abs(stats.zscore(df))
np.where(z > 3)`

i find a column of huge number of outliers not treated .

Shall I do something in this case .

Thank You

Comment: Your code is difficult to read. Can you post a more complete example that has a sample dataframe?

Comment: i want just to replace the outliers by the mean value of each column in my dataframe.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude here, but the sample code you provided is not runnable as is. I'm asking you to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Moving a bunch of data points to the mean is going to seriously decrease your standard deviation. That makes more data points "outliers" by your criteria when you check again. It is a very poor idea to change data values - either drop the outliers or don't, but don't pretend that they're equal to the mean.

Comment: @CJ59 thank you for your response .. Shall i replace it with median ?

Comment: I guess the question is what are you hoping to accomplish here? Why do you want to get rid of outliers, and assuming you've got a reason to do so, why don't you want to just drop them?

Comment: because in this case i will lose a big number of observation.. So i decided to replace them by the mean

Comment: Is the next thing you want to do with this data set some sort of statistical test? If you tell people you moved the data points farthest from to the mean then they will (correctly) not trust your conclusions from the test. If you don't tell them then you're committing whatever type of fraud is most applicable to your career. I don't think that what you want to do is a good idea.

Comment: So you propose that i delete them .? regardless of their huge number

Comment: The very nature of outliers is that if you have a huge number of them, you don't really have any. My opinion is that you should leave them in for whatever your analysis is and accept the fact that your variance is high.

Comment: but if delete all these observation that contains ouliers .. I will have just 3 lines in my new database.(from 20000 as input)

Comment: If you change the data in 19997 out of 20000 observations do you really think your analysis is going to be valid? You appear to have high-variability, high-dimensionality data. You should apply techniques that are appropriate for dealing with that kind of problem. What you have here isn't one of those techniques.